# Is there any problem opening 300MB+ audio files on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, audio-streaming, aac

I just recorded about 6 hours of AAC streaming into a file, resulting in 300 MB approximately. The file doesn't play. I wonder if there was any problem with the file format and content, or it is just the size of the file. If the latter, I wonder if I could split the file. If the former I wonder if I could fix this problem somehow or obtain more info about the data so I can troubleshoot.

Comment: 300MB is extremely small audio file.  Windows Media player is able to open a video file that is several times that size without a problem.  In other words the problem is with the file itself

Comment: But Windows Media Player says it found a problem playing the file.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree that's small when comparing with video files, but I never came across a 300MB+ audio before. Maybe there's a difference.

Comment: I would try opening it with Apple's Quicktime as it likes that extension. If it does not open, there is probably an issue with the file.

Comment: If the file extension is m4a the VLC player realizes it's a 6 hour audio file, but it is silent. VLC player plays MP3 files normally.

Comment: @KCotreau Quicktime doesn't recognize the file format

Comment: Mediamonkey says it couldn't decode the file, "probably because of DRM"

Comment: Download [audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), if audacity cant play it it's probably beyond help.

Comment: When I 7zip the file, it is almost uncompressable.

Comment: @Nifle Audacity doesn't open AAC files

Comment: It'd help if you told us *how* you recorded them.

Comment: @slhck I used VLC convert stream option

Comment: Windows Media player can be finkle sometimes.  I've noticed it with FLAC files.  But never with mp3 files. . .

Comment: @Ramhound @KCotreau @Nifle @slhck @surfasb I found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I didn't hit the Stop button on VLC. If the conversion is paused or interrupted the generated file becomes invalid.

One way to recover the file is to resume the conversion and then hit stop.

Comment: I couldn't resume the conversion once I closed VLC